# Slow Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress

my website http://www.serenity-place.co.uk/ is taking ages to load since I installed the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin and I cannot see why.

Answer (score 0):

It takes really long for your server to respond - you assets are loading pretty fast tough. So its probably because of your server setting. Where are you hosting? Is it a webspace,vserver,dedicated server,...

Interesting article: https://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/improve-server-response.html

[image: Server Response]

Comment: But it loads fast when I disable the plugin... its very confusing.

Comment: which plugin do you disable?

Comment: WooCommerce Subscriptions